# What was the origin of the Commission?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

Were the origins of the commission ever revealed in either the graphic novel or the TV version of *The Umbrella Academy*?

For example, were they human, or human-like aliens, where they from the prime universe or another universe\dimension?

Answer (score 1):

In the recent season, [S03E04](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13435926/?ref_=ttep_ep4) we do find out about the origin of the Commission,

### Spoiler ahead!

> Five and Lila find out that Commission's Founder is an elderly future version of Five with a missing arm and a cryptic tattoo. And he discourages them from saving the world.